# Adding a different object directory for Make

Tags: c, makefile

I want my make file to ouput (Object files .o) to a different subdirectory for example OBJECTS_DIR="./build"

I also want my .exe to be placed in DIST_DIR="./dist"

My make file below works(compiles & links) but in the same path.

```
# vars
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -c89 -Wall -g 
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
SOURCES_C = main.c A.c B.c C.c D.c E.c
INCLUDES=
OBJECTS_DIR=./build
DIST_DIR=./dist
PROGRAM = main

OBJECTS = $(SOURCES_C:.c=.o)

debug := CFLAGS

all debug: $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): $(INCLUDES) $(OBJECTS)
        $(LINK.c) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) 


clean:
        rm -f $(PROGRAM) $(OBJECTS)
```

How can I achieve outputing .o files to OBJECTS_DIR and then linking from OBJECTS_DIR & outputing the .exe to DIST_DIR.

Updated based on user recommendations:

```
# vars
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g 
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c89 -Wall -g
SOURCES_C = main.c A.c B.c C.c D.c E.c
OBJECTS_DIR := build
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES_C:%.c=$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o)
INCLUDES :=
DIST_DIR := dist
PROGRAM  := $(DIST_DIR)/main
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES_C:.c=.o)

debug := CFLAGS

all debug: $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM): $(INCLUDES) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) 


clean:
    rm -f $(PROGRAM) 
    rm -f $(OBJECTS)
```

I updated my Make & its works as expected.I have always relied on the IDE's to generate my Makefile.

1) Is there any issues that Im not aware of?

2) What is the point of the .PHONY (Still not getting that).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following makefile has not been tested

Note the use of ':=' for defining macros, so the macro only needs to be evaluated once

Note: the '.PHONY:' statements are to tell `make` that no file with the associated name (clean, all) will be generated

edited per Chris Dodd comments

```
CC           :=  /usr/bin/gcc
RM           :=  /bin/rm
CFLAGS       := -Wall -g -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11
SOURCES_C    := main.c A.c B.c C.c D.c E.c
OBJECTS_DIR  := build
DIST_DIR     := dist
PROGRAM      := $(DIST_DIR)/main
OBJECTS      := $(SOURCES_C:.c=$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o)

.PHONY: all
all: $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM):  $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) 

$(OBJECT_DIR)/%.o:%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c %$<  -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f $(PROGRAM) 
        rm -f $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: You need to add `$(OBJECTS_DIR)` before every element of `$(OBJECTS)`, not just the first.  So either do it when defining OBJECTS as `OBJECTS := $(SOURCES_C:%.c=$(OBJECTS_DIR)/%.o)` or when using it as `$(addprefix $OBJECT_DIR)/,$(OBJECTS))` (but not both)

Comment: You might also want a phony rule `$(PROGRAM): $(DIST_DIR)/$(PROGRAM)` or even `%: $(DIST_DIR)/%` (or just add the prefix in the `all` rule)